# Knockout Sortable list not working offset by new items added

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js, jquery-ui-sortable, knockout-sortable

When I add items to my list (by clicking the "add series" button) it causes my list to not sort properly. E.G. If I click the "add series" button and then try to move "seriesname232" inbetween items "trrde" and "1", then it will move it down one more than it should (below the "1"). I believe that this is because the sortable list isn't taking into account that something was added to it. Below is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/thebassix/yTAXh/

```
<div id="results">
            ---Hidden---
            <ul id="hidden" data-bind="sortable: { data: hiddenSeries, afterMove: hide}">
                <li data-bind="visible: Hidden, text: Name"></li>
            </ul>

    ---Unhidden---         
            <ul id="unhidden" data-bind="sortable: { data: unhiddenSeries, afterMove: unhide}">
                <li data-bind="visible: !Hidden(), text: Name"></li>
            </ul>
</div>
<hr/>
<div>All</div>
<ul data-bind="foreach: series">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: Name"></span> - 
        (<span data-bind="text: Hidden"></span>)
    </li>
</ul>
<input id="btnAddSeries" data-bind="click: addSeries" title="Add Series" class="ews_button" type="button" value="Add Series" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the `Series` object that you are adding has `_destroy` as an observable. Generally, `_destroy` is just a normal property, as the `destroy` function of KO set's it as a normal property.

So, your issue will be fixed, if you do not make `_destroy` an observable in your `Series` constructor like:

```
self._destroy = data._destroy;
```

Updated sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/63rup/

Additionally, I just added a [fix](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable/commit/5e0408c28c3b1bb80335db74c4b0d2161d4d121b) to the `sortable` plugin that will unwrap `_destroy` anyways, so this would not have been a problem.